# how to do an ultrachart with 2 columns of a Datatable containing 4

Tags: c#, datatable, infragistics

I made a Datatable with 4 columns : Date , Data1, Data2, Data4 . I would like to know how to represent in an XY ultrachart  Date versus Data4 ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Look at the sample browser: [Link](http://samples.infragistics.com/aspnet/Samples/WebCharts/Display/Bar-And-Column-Charts/Bar-Charts/Default.aspx?cn=chart&sid=24b618aa-b729-4a76-8dcd-d48a40e13944)  Here is shown how to make BarChart with XY axis. Look at the C# file where is show how the BarChart is datasorced and databound - your functions for insert, delete should handle the whole row, update  and select should include only the desired two columns :) Try to use this sample as a guide.